# Joining two tables to update results in third table using like

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am trying to join two tables and update the results in the third table.
So **table A** is the results table and it has the columns **customer number and score.**

**Table B has customer number and ind_code** and **table C has ind_code and ind_score.**

So the output of the query should be such that the **ind_code in table B and C should join together based on the first two digits and ind_score should be updated in Table A in the score column.** **Table A and Table B should be joined** on the basis of **customer number**.

Could anyone please help. I tried multiple queries but nothing seems to work. i am using **oracle sql developer**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the `JOIN` operation mustn't cut field information but if your structure (for me not correct) is that ...

If I understand better:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET score =
(SELECT MAX(C.ind_score)
FROM TableC C
JOIN TableB B
    ON C.ind_code = SUBSTRING(B.ind_code, 1, 2)
WHERE B.customernumber = TableA.customernumber)
```

I use on subquery `MAX` aggregate function, because I don't know if your cut of ind_code of TableB can be not unique (i.e. you have ind_code 5555 and 5554)

Comment: but in B if you have these rows: (123, 5555); (123, 5554); (123, 5553) my subquery (without MAX) returns more than row, so goes in error. With max I take the max score (I think in Table C you have only row (55, .214). Try my script

Comment: Dear, because you are newbie. If the answer accomplighes your question please accept it (clicking on tick) and upvote it (clicking on up arrow)